# Finding cloud cover score of Landsat image?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I want to find cloud cover of an image
This is my code:

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
    .filterBounds(district)
    .filterDate('2015-03-01','2015-05-01')
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .map(maskClouds)
    .median();
```

I tried this code:

```
var getCloudScores = function(image)
{
    //Get the cloud cover
    var value = ee.Image(image).get('CLOUD_COVER');
    return ee.Feature(null, {'score': value})
};

var results = landsat.map(getCloudScores);

print(Chart.feature.byFeature(results));
```

It is giving me error:

> landsat is not defined in this scope.

How do I calculate cloud cover and which variable I should use in place of landsat?

Comment: `landsat` is not defined in this scope because you don't have an imageCollection called `landsat`. Use the cloud scores function on your image and you should get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would make sense to get a cloud score from an imageCollection that has been reduced to a single median image. Instead, by removing the cloud mask, median reducer, and sorting step when you assign your imageCollection, you can map the `getCloudScores` function to all images in the collection. Note that I include a different district because yours isn't declared in the code you provide. Additionally, I made the date filter a little longer to demonstrate what the cloud cover time series looks like with more than just 3 observations.

```
var maineCounties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Waldo'));
print(maineCounties);
var district = maineCounties;

var imageColl = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
    .filterBounds(district)
    .filterDate('2015-03-01','2015-08-01');
print("image",imageColl);


var getCloudScores = function(image)
{
    //Get the cloud cover
    var value = image.get('CLOUD_COVER');
    return ee.Feature(null, {'score': value});
};

var results = imageColl.map(getCloudScores);

print(Chart.feature.byFeature(results));
```